# Java EE: unzipping a BLOB and get the file inside

Tags: oracle, jakarta-ee, zip, blob

I'm building a Java EE application, and in my servlet i'm retrieving a BLOB from a Oracle Database.

The query works perfectly.

Now I don't know exactly in what format the BLOB is, it should be a sort of a zipped file, since in SQL Developer I can save it on my desktop, rename it with .ZIP extension, unzip it, and inside I can find a TXT file.

So it should be a txt file been zipped.

I would like to retrieve the txt file content in my Java Servlet. So unzip the file and read the txt file.

I've tried using GZIPInputStream:

```
gStream = new GZIPInputStream(blob.getBinaryStream());
```

as explained [here, at the end of the file](http://www.developerfusion.com/article/84515/smaller-is-better-8211-shrink-your-world-with-java-compression-apis/)

but i get the exception: "Not in GZIP format".

So can you please help me?

- Do I need on first to unzip the BLOB?
- And then how to get the txt file inside?

Answer (score 3):

[Zip](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zip_%28file_format%29) and [Gzip](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gzip) are completely different formats.  The former is an *archive* and *compression* format, the latter is only a *compression* format.  You need an input stream that understands the zip format, try [`ZipInputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipInputStream.html) instead.

Comment: ok, i'm trying it... But having a ZipInputStream object,  how  can I retrieve the content of the txt file inside the zipped blob?

Comment: I also create a file using FileOutputStream from the ZipInputStream, but the file is empty... and which file is it going to write ? The zipped one or the TXT inside it? ...hmmm

Comment: gZipStream = new ZipInputStream(blob.getBinaryStream());

byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
Displaying gZipStream.read(buf) the result is -1...